# Why do I get "'VideoSource' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Tags: typescript

In the first if check I don't get an error, nut in the else if I get

> 'VideoSource' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```ts
let element:VideoSource|VideoTrack;
element = {
    src: '',
    videoType: 'video/mp4'
}

if (element instanceof  VideoTrack) {

}
else if (element instanceof  VideoSource) {

}

export interface VideoSource {
    src:string;
    videoType:'video/mp4'|'video/webm'|'video/ogg';
}

export interface VideoTrack {
    src:string;
    kind: 'subtitles'|'captions'|'chapters'|'descriptions'|'metadata'
    label?:string;
    srclang?:string;
    IsDefault?:'default';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19120#issuecomment-335989615) to an issue on the typescript GitHub.
Also this [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11807#issuecomment-255657603).

Basically, because Interfaces only exist at compile-time and are removed after compilation, you can't use them to do checks at run-time. Note that it is possible with classes.

Comment: But why does the _VideoTrack_ interface work?

Comment: That appears to be a [built in type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoTrack), when I hover it in my IDE (vs code) it shows that it has a prototype and constructor, so it is a class and is present at run-time.

Comment: Remove your _VideoTrack_ interface and you'll see that it still works